# How to check if any element of a list of lists contains all the element of another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to check if any element of a list of lists contains all the elements of another list in Python. Now I am doing it with a for loop, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way. For example, I want to check if any list in b contains all the elements of the list a, not necessarily in the same order:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 9], [1, 3, 6, 2]]

for j in b:
 all(elem in j for elem in a)
 print('True')
 break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is set operations.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 9], [1, 3, 6, 2]]    
sa = set(a)

for j in b:
    # creating a set(j) here as we only need to create a set
    # if we haven't found it yet.
    # if you are going to keep running this many times, then maybe
    # create a new list sb = [set(j) for j in b] outside the forloop
    # and iterate over that.
    if sa.issubset(set(j)):
         print("True")
         break
```

For smaller values, lists are fine. But as `a` or `b[i]` grows large, that check will become slow on lists.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if `b` is so short, but you could avoid creating the second list of all of the sets in advance by either making it a generator with `sb = (set(j) for j in b)`, or more simply using  `if sa.issubset(set(sj)):`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I have a lot of lists in b, and looping through this long list of lists is sometimes slow. I was looking for a way to avoid a for loop.

Comment: @AndreaBelle This is sort of a needle and haystack problem - you're looking for a particular set of numbers from many sets of numbers. The only way you can return false is by making sure it isn't in any of the lists - so at worst you would have to iterate over every element in b. What you can do is make each iteration faster - using a set is faster than a list. Faster tricks would depend on knowing your data - if each list never has duplicates, you could immediately filter lesser length lists and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten `b` using `sum(b, [])`, covert both `a` and `b` to sets and compare them

```
bool(set(a) & set(sum(b, [])))
```

Note that `set(a) & set(sum(b, []))` returns `{1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you want to avoid a for loop, but any process is going to have to essentially iterate across `b`, performing the comparisons one by one.

One alternative that uses `map()` rather than an explicit loop is:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 4, 9], [1, 3, 6, 2]]

c = list(map(lambda x : set(a).issubset(set(x)), b))
```

This returns:

```
>>> [False, False, True]
```

This is essentially doing the same comparison as the earlier answer from @algrebe, but in a different way. You would have to do time comparisons to find out if one method works faster than another in your particular scenario.